# Grunt-open: Spawn ENOENT

Tags: gruntjs

I keep getting "Warning: Spawn ENOENT" problem when I am running grunt-open.

My setup

I have all my project files on Google Drive.
I am doing my development on the files directly on them (using Google Drive desktop).

I just want to open the index.html file when I run grunt. Just that simple.

Part of my Gruntfile.js

```
 open: {
  all: {
    path : 'index.html'
  }
},
```

But I couldn't get it working? What am I missing?

Comment: I have tested my code on another machine at work and it works fine.
I don't get the ENOENT problem. I did a lot of Google search, it seems to be something about the environment variable? It couldn't locate Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out.
You have to change your system environment variable to include the following if on PC.

%SystemRoot%\system32;

Comment: I had a similar problem with Grunt where msbuild would only complete successfully if ran from an Admin prompt. Some program's installer had modified & broke my windows path and cmd was not being found in `%systemroot%\system32`. I fixed up the path and all is better.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. My system environment 'Path' variable already contained this. I get `Fatal error: spawn ENOENT` when I try to run `grunt phpunit` and I get `Warning: spawn ENOENT` when I try to run `grunt shell`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for `grunt-run` task:

```
run: {
    jasmine: {
        cmd: 'jasmine-node.cmd',
        args: ['--autotest', '--test-dir', 'test']
    }
},
```

You have to specify `jasmine-node.cmd` as *cmd* - not just `jasmine-node` which is enough when running from command line.